# Should I install my old graphics card on my new system with integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm in the process of upgrading my computer. I've bought a new motherboard, RAM, CPU and hard disks.

The new CPU is an Intel i7-4790K. The new system has integrated graphics and my old system had a dedicated **Nvidia GTS 450** graphics card.

Should I install the graphics card in the new system or will the integrated graphics be better since the graphics card is a few years old?

Comment: The iGPU that the `4790K` is faster then your `GTS 650`.  Your old GPU isn't worth even using.

Comment: It's actually a **GTS 450**, not a 650. Turns out the old card is slightly quicker, so worth installing for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old **Nvidia GTS 450** card is slightly faster than the integrated **Intel HD Graphics 4600**.

I ran three different benchmark suites (3DMark, Passmark PerformanceTest and Userbenchmark). Under all of them, the *GTS 450* was consistently quicker.

I also tested video rendering using *Cyberlink PowerDirector 14*. Render times (average over three runs) on a 20 second video clip with color grading applied resulted in 4:40 for the *4600* and 4:35 for the *GTS 450* - 5 seconds quicker.

[3DMark comparison](http://www.3dmark.com/compare/fs/6368168/fs/6358513)